# Selecting id (in this case dupersid) where value from the second column (in this case icd9codx) is in (296, 311) and 250 only

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

Selecting id (in this case dupersid) where value from the second column (in this case icd9codx) is in (296, 311) and  250 only.

---

```
| dupersid  | icd9codx
---------------------
46166101    -9
46166101    250
46166101    272
46166101    272
46166101    311
46166101    401
46166101    460
46166101    701
46166101    715
46166101    719
46166101    780
46166102    250
46166102    311
46166103    250
46166103    296
```

Expected Result

```
----------------------
dupersid    icd9codx
---------------------
46166102    250
46166102    311
46166103    250
46166103    296
```

I tried

```
SELECT dupersid, icd9codx FROM public.sample_test
WHERE icd9codx = 250 AND dupersid IN (select distinct dupersid from public.sample_test where icd9codx IN (296, 311));
```

but it also gives records like 46166101

Comment: 46166101 is in there because it has records where icd9codx IN (296, 311) ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with trick of summing the powers of 2:

```
SELECT * 
FROM public.sample_test 
WHERE dupersid IN(SELECT dupersid FROM public.sample_test
                  GROUP BY dupersid
                  HAVING SUM(CASE icd9codx WHEN 250 THEN 1
                                           WHEN 296 THEN 2 
                                           WHEN 311 THEN 4
                                           ELSE 8 END) IN (3, 5) AND
                         SUM(CASE WHEN icd9codx = 250 THEN 1  
                                  ELSE 0 END) = 1)
```

Comment: Thank Giorgi. I apologize but just realized that what I want is dupersid with icd9codx = ( 296 or 311 ) and 250 but nothing else. I will edit question to reflect that. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Can be there 3 at the same time?i.e. 296 311 and 250? Or 250 296 296?

Comment: No, the result set should be dupersid with either (296 and 250) or (311 and 250 )

Comment: In simple words this means patients with diabetes and depression, but no other diseases. Code: 296 or 311 represents depression and 250 diabetes

Comment: I have added one more check because there can be 3 rows with 250 only and without additional chech you would get that row.

Comment: this is a brilliant solution. I would have never been able to get this by myself. Thanks a lot